# Twilio MMS Number

Tags: twilio

I am using the software DSLR-Photobooth. Included is Twilio to send the made pictures directly. Twilio-site says I need a number for that, but there are just SMS and voice numbers. How can I get a MMS Number?

Thanks
Enrico

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

Enrico, where are you trying to buy a number in order to [start sending MMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages)?

You may want to check out [this list](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/phone-numbers/which-countries-does-twilio-have-phone-numbers-in-and-what-are-their-capabilities) of SMS enabled numbers and look for 'Yes' in the MMS enabled box.

Comment: But can I use for example a canadian number for sending MMS in germany? or is that more expensive? Because the german number are not able to send MMS.

Comment: At this time, MMS messaging can only be sent within US and Canada. International MMS messaging outside these two countries is not yet supported, however MMS messages sent internationally will be converted to SMS text messages with a URL link to the media. MMS messages sent in the US or Canada to unsupported carriers will also be sent via SMS. https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-i-send-or-receive-mms-messages